# Conditions for equality of two binomial sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $k,r,n$ be integers such that $0<k,r<n$. Let

$$K=\sum^n_{i=k}k^{n-i}\binom{n-k}{i-k}^2k!(i-k)! \,\text{ and }\, R=\sum^n_{i=r}r^{n-i}\binom{n-r}{i-r}^2r!(i-r)!.$$

How to show that "$K=R\:\Rightarrow\: k=r$"? But if it does not holds, I want to see a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

For $(k, r, n) = (1, 2, 2)$, we have
\begin{align*}
K = \sum_{i=1}^2 \binom{1}{i-1} (i-1)!
 = \binom{1}{0} + \binom{1}{1} 
 = 2
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
R = \sum_{i=2}^22^{2-i} \; 2!\;(i-2)!
  = 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much. If I add the condition that $0<k,r<n$, Can you find an another example?

Comment: I haven't found any counterexamples with $n\leq 12$. The function grows rapidly enough that it looks like there aren't any $k\not = r$ for a fixed $n$ with the same value, if only by coincidence.

Comment: Under the condition how to prove $k\neq r\,\Rightarrow K\neq R$ ?